# PhantomJs and Nodejs very slow

Tags: node.js, web-services, rest, web-scraping, phantomjs

I have created a rest service with nodejs, where for the response it goes to a certain page and scrape some date using the phantomjs version of nodejs.

The whole process is very **slow** (I had to move to another server because some connections were automatically timeout after **30 seconds**).

Another problem (as is my understanding) is that the server is single thread so it takes even a lot more to respond if it is already processing another request. 
My questions are:

1. Is there a way **to speed up** the whole process?
2. Is there a way to make the **nodejs run multithreaded**?
3. Most important would a **Java** implementaion of the same services (with selenium)  would be faster or allow multithreading? Thanks

Comment: node.js is synchronous, however, the request to the target server and most of the phantomjs portion of it is not, so, no, it won't slow down other requests as much as you may think.

Comment: You need to diagnose what exactly is causing it to be slow. The connections to external servers, the processing of the returned html, etc.

Comment: It slows because of the parsing done by phantomjs (i evalute code in the context of the loaded pages) and for loading a page. 
I just tested it and you are right - the server responds to other requests at the same time, but it can't complete more scraping jobs at the same time and i don't understand why.

Comment: I think i should mention that i am running on a free instance of heroku which has 512 mb of RAM.

Comment: Are you monitoring your process during the tests?

Comment: No. Shouldn't nodejs be a single process?

Comment: sure, node is, but there's more than node running on your server (phantomjs for example)

Comment: I'll definitely look into that.

Comment: On heroku the only way i found to show processes is with heroku:ps and it only shows me the node process (node.js) (even if i have 7 requests for web scraping at the same time). I think i should research more alternative for hosting that offer greater control and insestigate further.

Comment: try a micro aws instance for testing. It's free for the first year on new accts. well, free-ish, unless you use up the monthly free bandwidth.